# вывод внесенных данных из таблицы в таблицу php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

не могу вывести данные

```html
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       getConect();
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $name_equipment = ($_POST['name_equipment']);
    $inv_number = ($_POST['inv_number']);
    $image = ($_POST['image']);
    $description = ($_POST['description']);
    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO`equipment`(`name_equipment`,`inv_number`,`image`,`description`)
    VALUES ("'.$name_equipment.'","'.$inv_number.'","'.$image.'","'.$description.'")');
    $query=mysql_query('SELECT*FROM`equipment`(`name_equipment`,`inv_number`,`image`,`description`)');
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     echo "<td>".$result ['name_equipment']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$result ['inv_number']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$result ['image']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$result ['description']."</td></tr>";
    
    }
      
   }
}
?>
```

с базой соединение есть в таблицы equipment идут записи!

это форма кнопки для отправления

```html
 </tr>
 <h3>Добавление оборудования</h3>
   <form method="post" action = 'action/?method=addform'>
   <span class="label"> Название </span>
   <input style="width: 5%;" type="text" class="input" name="name_equipment" >
   

   <span class="label">Инвентарный </span>
   <input style="width: 10%;" type="text" class="input" name="inv_number" >
   
   <span class="label">Картинка </span>
   <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="image" >

   <span class="label">Примечание </span>
   <input style="width: 15%;" class="input" name="description" >
  
   <br/>
   <br /><input type = "submit" name = "add" value ="Добавить"/><br />
   <br /> 
            </form>
  </tbody>
```

отправляется в файл action там метод

```html
else if($method=='addform'){
$name_equipment = getCheck($_POST['name_equipment'],'text');
     $inv_number = getCheck($_POST['inv_number'],'int');
     $image = getCheck($_POST['image'],'text');
     $description = getCheck($_POST['description'],'text');
     if($name_equipment!=''AND $inv_number!=''AND $description!=''){
      $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO`equipment`(`name_equipment`,`inv_number`,`image`,`description`)
     VALUES ("'.$name_equipment.'","'.$inv_number.'","'.$image.'","'.$description.'")');
  else {
     exit('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=../page/journal1/" />');
          }
          }
```

Comment: А зачем вам пытаться получить из таблицы, то, что вы и так знаете? Вы же пытаетесь вывести значения, которые только, что внесли. Они у вас в виде переменных уже есть

Comment: где `select` запрос то? и да, обычно `while($row = fetch($query))` а не `$query = fetch $row`

Comment: @wcobalt есть форма ввода данных и форма таблицы в одном файле я ввожу после данные должны быть в таблице на странице

Comment: @teran ой перепутал  и так и так все равно не выводит

Comment: ну дак селект запроса то все равно нет у вас, кого выводите то?

Comment: @teran типо так я новичок поэтому не понимаю да и код не мой воот и сижу голову ломаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, вот, что вам нужно:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        getConect();
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $name_equipment = $_POST['name_equipment'];
        $inv_number = $_POST['inv_number'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO`equipment`(`name_equipment`,`inv_number`,`image`,`description`)
                    VALUES ("'.$name_equipment.'","'.$inv_number.'","'.$image.'","'.$description.'")');

        echo "<td>".$name_equipment."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$inv_number."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$image."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$description."</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: нет так уже пробывал вывода нет

Comment: @DumanTursynbay если вывода нет, значит в таблицу вставляются пустые значения. Следовательно, вы неправильно отправляете данные из html-формы. Покажите ваш html

Comment: @DumanTursynbay в таблице значения появляются?

Comment: как это не правильно в таблице phpmyadmin форма заполняется моими данными а вывод сделать там же не могу

Comment: да есть значения их то и не могу вывести

Comment: @DumanTursynbay т.е. вы после нажатия на кнопку, получаете пустую страницу?

Comment: нет страница обновляется но данные не выходят

Comment: @DumanTursynbay все правильно, вы находясь на странице page/journal1 отправляете данные на другую страницу там они выводятся, но после этого происходит перенаправление обратно на страницу page/journal1. Соответственно ничего не выводится. Уберите например exit() и посмотрите что получится

Comment: перенаправил на страницу  http://localhost/Work_Log/action/?method=addform которого я не создовал он же там в journal1 есть таблица и вывод должен там же сделать

Comment: @DumanTursynbay смотрите: у вас есть начальная страница, и скрипт action, в него вы посылаете данные с нач. страницы, он их вставляет в БД и выводит - но сразу после этого он перенаправляет пользователя на нач. стр. и вывода там нет (так как это перенаправление равносильно просто прямому открытию данной страницы в браузере). Чтобы вывод был на той странице откуда идут данные, надо менять архитектуру. Например чтобы обрабатывающий скрипт был расположен на нач. странице или (что наверное лучше) после обработки скрипт перен. на нач. стр. но при этом в строку запроса добавляет флаговую переменную

Comment: @DumanTursynbay например `add`, скрипт это видит и достает последнюю запись из бд (Хотя для безопасности лучше не флаговую переменную, а обычную содержащую хеш сессии пользователя или чего-нибудь подобного)